# Autofilling Event Title in Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I am attempting to get the event in my Full Calendar to autofill with the word "Reserved" when a user creates a new event. I have the variable set to prompt the user with a text box and they can input any text string. Anyone know how to have the Event Title be autofilled or named?

Here is the code I am using for the event title right now:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
  if (event.allDay === 'true') {
    event.allDay = true;
  } else {
    event.allDay = false;
  }
},   

selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
var title = prompt('Confirm Email:','<?php echo "{$_SESSION['email']}"; ?>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the user to be able to choose the title then the obvious thing to do would be to remove the `prompt()` command (which is the bit which tells the script to ask the user to input something) and just set the variable directly from the injected Session value.

```
var title = '<?php echo $_SESSION["email"]; ?>';
```

Although I note also that you perhaps actually wanted it to say "Reserved" rather than including the user's email? If so then it's even simpler:

```
var title = "Reserved";
```

N.B. This is really just about the different ways to give a value to a variable in JavaScript. There's nothing particularly specific to fullCalendar or even PHP here - what you do with the variable after you've set its value is largely irrelevant to how you set it in the first place.